# directly update a field using a primary key in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am not sure if this is possible, but I have to do it a lot.
I have a single field that needs updating.
The way I am doing it via a SP would be:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE UpdPODPDFURLByStopID
    @Stop_Detail_Id int,
    @POD_PDF_URL varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE Stop_Detail
    SET     
        POD_PDF_URL = @POD_PDF_URL
    WHERE
        Id = @Stop_Detail_Id

END
```

Then call that by:

```
 int count = context.UpdPODPDFURLByStopID(Convert.ToInt32(lobStop["stopId"]), pdfUrl);
```

Or I am doing something like:

```
var recordToUpdate = db.Driver_Detail.Find(newTopHatDriver);
recordToUpdate.record_note = "test Note";
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a way to just directly tell the context to update a record directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update your entity without acquiring it first from the db

```
var record = new Driver_Detail
{
    ID = 1, //ID of an entity you want to edit
    POD_PDF_URL = "field you want to edit"
};

db.Attach(record);
db.Entry(record).Property(rec => rec.POD_PDF_URL).IsModified = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

If entity with given id does not exist in the databse it will throw DbUpdateConcurrencyException, it will not try to add it. State of an entity is changed to "Modiefied", not "Added". [Entity states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state)

Comment: interesting, am I wrong in reading that will only be adding a new record?  What I am needing to do is modify a current records specific field.  Am I reading that incorrectly?